# Mongoose pre/post midleware can't access [this] instance using ES6

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have dilemma, trying to add some pre-logic to a mongoose model using `pre` middleware and can not access the `this` instance as usual.

```
UserSchema.pre('save', next => {
    console.log(this); // logs out empty object {}

    let hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
    let password = this.password;

    console.log("Hashing password, " + password);

    hash.update(password);
    this.password = hash.digest('hex');

    next();
  });
```

Question: *Is there a way to access the `this` instance?

Comment: [He is in trouble](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3695) similar your situation. As the maintainer said, retaining context is a feature of arrow notation, you should use `function () {}` notation and it will give you (and your co-worker) the meaning that it doesn't work with retaining context using arrow notation.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The fat arrow notation (`=>`) is not useful in this situation. Instead, just use the old fashioned anonymous function notation:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  ...
});
```

The reason is that the fat arrow lexically binds the function to the current scope (more on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), but TL;DR: the fat arrow notation is not meant to be a generic shortcut notation, it's meant specifically to create lexically bound functions), whereas the function *should* be called in a scope provided by Mongoose.

Comment: That is correct, but you might want to add a reference to [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), potentially quoting the reason why they cannot be used here. ;)

Comment: I did eventually revert the code to the old (`function(next){}`) notation but I wonder how to bypass this issue, maybe use the `mongoose.model('User', UserSchema).password`  i tried and it not seems to work.

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru there's still a reason for the old notation to exist, so even though the fat arrow notation may look better, it's not meant to be used in this particular case.

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru That _issue_ simply derives from using the wrong construct. Just don't use arrow functions there, or any other case where you need to use the bound `this`.

Comment: Hello life-saver!

Comment: Here's a really good link that explains more about arrow function usage and lexically binding of `this`: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/javascriptarrowfunctions2.shtml

 ... "Arrow functions are just like regular anonymous functions, with one major exception...[they] deviate from regular functions in the way the "this" object inside them behaves..the "this" object inside a arrow function is lexically bound, which is just a fancy way of saying its value is static and determined by the scope `this` is defined in..."