# Password doesn't hash/encrypt before being saved into the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bcrypt

I am using mongoose and bcrypt-nodejs. Before saving into the database I run .pre('save') middleware where bcrypt hashes user's password before calling next. However a non-hashed password gets saved into the database.

Here is my code:

User model:

```
 33 userSchema.pre('save', (next: any) => {
 34   var user = this;
 35
 36   bcrypt.hash(user.password, null, null, (err: any, hash: string) => {
 37     user.password = hash;
 38     next();
 39   })
 40 });
 41
 42 userSchema.methods.registerUser = function(body: any, cb: any) {
 43   this.username = body.username;
 44   this.email = body.email;
 45   this.password = body.password;
 46   cb();
 47 };
```

User controller:

```
 10 router.post('/register', (req: any, res: any) => {
 11   var user = new User({});
 12   user.registerUser(req.body, (err: any) => {
 13     user.save(function(err: any) {
 14       if (err) res.render('users/register', { page: 1, error: err.errors });
 15       else console.log("User Saved!");
 16       console.log(user);
 17     });
 18   });
 19 });
```

Console output:

```
User Saved!
{ __v: 0,
  password: 'secret',
  email: 'dorian3@gmail.com',
  username: 'dorian3',
  _id: 57c955180ca45d5e074f5763 }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is about the error which is not defined in the hashing structure.Try adding the  line  //if(err) return next(err); after bcrypt.hash() function

Comment: Don't see why. I `console.log(hash)` and it logged the generated hash

Comment: I tried adding `if(err) return next(err)` after bcrypt.hash() but my tsc compiler outputted `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'err'.`

Comment: This is most likely a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36957440/mongoose-pre-post-midleware-cant-acces-this-instance-using-es6).

Comment: Thank you! Because of the arrow function it didn't work. Now it is fixed.