# Issue setting virtuals between documents in Mongoose (node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having an issue attempting to set virtuals for individual Documents. Basically I'm trying to have my document hold onto values that I don't actually want saved in the database. Here is sample code.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const bookSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
}, {
  toObject: { virtuals: true },
  toJSON: { virtuals: false }
})

bookSchema.virtual('desc').get(() => {
    return this.__desc
}).set((val) => {
    this.__desc = val
})

const bookModel = mongoose.model('book', bookSchema)

let first_book = new bookModel()
first_book.title = "desc should be first"
first_book.desc = "first"

console.log("FIRST BOOK", first_book,"\n","\n")

let second_book = new bookModel()
second_book.title = "desc should be second"
second_book.desc = "second"

console.log("FIRST BOOK AGAIN", first_book)
```

When I output `first_book` I get `desc: 'first'` as expected. However, when I output it after setting `second_book.desc = "second"`, for some reason the `desc` virtual for `first_book` has changed. I can't seem to find any documentation on the scope for virtuals, but I would expect `first_book.desc` to remain `first`.

Am I doing this wrong? Is there another way to have documents hold onto data that doesn't belong in the database?

Comment: Don't use fat arrows, it'll break `this` inside your virtual getter/setter. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36957440/mongoose-pre-post-midleware-cant-acces-this-instance-using-es6) (amongst others).

Comment: Add your comment as an answer so I can mark correctly plz