# Type Error while getting instance of a model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I've added a hook to get an instance of User model to encrypt the user passwords.But im unable to get an instance of the model.

This my code

```
regUsers.pre('save',(next)=>{
      // get access to this user model
      const user = this;

      // generate salt the run call back
      bcrypt.genSalt(10,(err,salt)=>{

         if(err){ return next(err);}

        // hash(encrypt) our password using salt
         bcrypt.hash(user.password,salt,null,(err,hash)=>{

              if(err){ return next(err);}

              //overwrite plain text password with encrypted password
              user.password = hash;

              next();
         });
      })
});
```

Im getting a Type error as
TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined.
Any reason why im getting this erorr? and how to overcome this?

Comment: `this` would be referring to instance of `mongoose.Query`..

Comment: @SunilBN in this case a `document middleware` is being used, `this` is a reference to the document being updated, not to the query. Here is explained: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose pre/post midleware can't acces \[this\] instance using ES6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36957440/mongoose-pre-post-midleware-cant-acces-this-instance-using-es6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), try with a classic function expression.

Possibly Mongoose is calling that callback using `call()` or `apply()` (or something similar) to give it the desired context (in this case, a reference to the document being updated).